# How to config Rollup for subpath components

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I'm new to Rollup. I'd like to rollup my components to use them in mulitple projects.
My filestructure is

- src /

  - Button

    - Button.tsx
    - Button.css
    - GreenButton.tsx
    - GreenButton.css
    - BlueButton.tsx
    - BlueButton.css
  - Dropdown

    - Dropdown.tsx
    - Dropdown.css
  - ...

I dont want to create a single index.js with all components, see here: https://medium.com/singapore-gds/how-to-support-subpath-imports-using-react-rollup-typescript-1d3d331f821b

So my goal is to create a package with all my Components, which can by imported by "my-package/Button".

## Getting all Modules

I even do not know how go get all my modules. Do I have to list them in an array? Can I get all js/jsx/ts/tsx-files be a module?

## Filestructure

If I understand it correct, I need a filestructure for my package like this:

- dist

  - Button

    - Button.js
    - Button.css
    - Button.d.ts
    - package.json
    - GreenButton

      - GreenButton.js
      - GreenButton.css
      - GreenButton.d.ts
      - package.json
    - ...
  - ...

## Compiling Components

My components have to be compiled to js/jsx files to be used, if the other project is not using typescript. I would like to compile to esnext and jsx should be preserved.
The plan is that the code is easier to understand, if someone wants to jump inside the code in node_modules. (Open implementation in VSCode)

The declaration files have to be generated for Intellisense and Typescript.

## Component imports

If I understand this correct, imports in my component have to be handled in a specific way.

- External Librarys are not bundled in my Component.
- Imports of other Components are not bundled in my Component.
  (Do they have to be renamed to import "my-package/othercomponent"?)
- Other Ressource Files (css, ...) have to be bundled with plugins (postcss, ...)

## Creating Package.json

Package.json has to be generated to link js and types for each component.

The structure of package.json has to be:

```
{
  "module": "./Button.js",
  "types": "./Button.d.ts"
}
```

## My Approach

My actual approach is:

1. Getting all js/jsx/ts/tsx-files
2. Create an Rollup-entry for each module

   1. Check if filename not equals foldername, then add subfolder to output
   2. Check if ts/tsx, then add typescript plugin to plugins
   3. Check if tsx/jsx, then add acorn-jsx to acornInjectPlugins

This is my rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import jsx from 'acorn-jsx';
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

import path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const options = {
    inDir: "./src",
    outDir: "./dist",
    include: [/.*\\.*\.[jt]sx?$/],
    exclude: [/\.test\./, /\.d\.ts$/]
}

function getFiles(basePath, relPath, include, exclude){
    return fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(basePath, relPath), {withFileTypes: true}).reduce((list, element) => {
        const relElement = path.join(relPath, element.name);
        if(exclude && exclude.some(exclude => exclude.test(relElement))){
            return list;
        }
        if(element.isDirectory()){
            return list.concat(getFiles(basePath, relElement, include, exclude));
        }
        if(include.some(include => include.test(relElement))){
            return list.concat(relElement);
        };
        return list;
    },[]);
}
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));


let modules = getFiles(path.resolve(__dirname, options.inDir), "./", options.include, options.exclude);

function convertExt(ext){
    switch(ext){
        case ".tsx": return ".jsx";
        case ".ts": return ".js";
        default: return ext;
    }
}

function createRollupEntry(module){
    let ext = path.extname(module);
    let file = path.basename(module, ext);
    let directory = path.dirname(module);
    let folder = path.basename(directory);

    let outputExt = convertExt(ext);

    let input = path.join(options.inDir, module);
    let output = path.join(options.outDir, directory, file === folder ? "" : "file", file + outputExt);

    let rollupConfig = {
        input: input,
        output: {
            file: output,
            format: "esm"
        },
        plugins: [
            postcss({
                extract: true
            })
        ],
        external: id => !/.css$/.test(id)
    }

    if(outputExt === ".jsx") {
        rollupConfig.acornInjectPlugins = [jsx()];
    }

    if(/^\.tsx?$/.test(ext)){
        rollupConfig.plugins.push(
            typescript({
                tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
                include: input,
                compilerOptions: {
                    jsx: "preserve",
                    declaration: true
                }
            })
        )
    }

    return rollupConfig;

}
 export default modules.filter((_, index) => index < 1).map(element => {
    let entry = createRollupEntry(element);
    console.log(entry);
    return entry;
});
```

## Problems

But I got the following problems.

### 1. JSX-preserve

If I set jsx: "preserve" in compilerOptions and add acorn-jsx my import is not recognized correct.
In my code I have:

```
import { Component } from "external/component"

function Button() {
  return <Component />
}
```

and this is converted with the warning to

> Component imported from external module "external/component" but never used in "src/Button/Button.tsx"

```
import "external/component"

function Button() {
  return <Component />
}
```

Maybe the jsx is not tree-shaked any more.

### 2. handling import

How do I setup config to handle my external librarys?
How do I exclude my components? Should the Imports be renamed?
Actually I only have this:

```
external: id => !/.css$/.test(id)
```

### 3. package.json for each module

How to create the package.json?

How do I have to configure Rollup to build this task? Or is there an even simpler/better way to bundle my components?

Comment: This should help you https://medium.com/singapore-gds/how-to-support-subpath-imports-using-react-rollup-typescript-1d3d331f821b